# Web Service request is not working in android browser and code; but it is working in pc browser

Tags: java, android, web-services

My PC is connected to client's network via tunneling and I am calling a webservice which is in client's network. This works fine in PC Browsers, where as when I try to access it via android application I am getting **ClientProtocolException**. I tried to hit the web service ip via android browser I was able to see the IIS server response in browser but couldn't access the webservice. Not an https url, just normal http url. It's not working in any version of android emulator.

Code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

HttpResponse response;

try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    Log.i("Debug",response.getStatusLine().toString());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {

        ....
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is the url you are using? have you tried it from an actual device or just from emulator?

Comment: @ftom2:  actual url is in another network, I have connected my system to that network via tunnelling, so the url is working in pc browser. but it is not working in android emulator. I have tried all the possibility you have said

Comment: do you have proper permissions?

Comment: @ftom2 Permissions in the sense what are you asking?

Comment: in the sense of permissions in the manifest: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Due to your response to @ftom2, who suggested a manifest problem (which is often 99% of the time the issue) and the fact you assume we all know the Exception types off the back of our hands I am no longer going to provide assistance.

Comment: @GrahamSmith - Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Try and use a packet sniffer to see what's traveling on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no response headers in the webservice. That is why I got the exception. Now I opened a socket to get the response, but still a request without proper response header is not good.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a firewall application (there is none built-in to my knowledge) on your Android device that may be blocking the access to the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a Web proxy?

```
httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy("ip-address","port")
```

or

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "ip-address");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "port");
```

Comment: In my system itself I have made an exception for this IP to avoid proxy settings in-order to access the web-service from browser.

Comment: In this case, can you try replicating your problem in a proxy-free network? I think I have experienced this problem before. But can't explain it appropiately.